# MS Access Database insert values on a column using vba and sql query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Is there any way to add a column into an MS Access database using VBA and SQL query and then insert values using formulas from other column.

As an example, I want to create a column `employee` and it should have calculated values on all the records. I want to use `LEFT(col2, 3)` in the `employee` field.

This is my code:

```vb
Sub createcolumn()
    Dim objAccess As Object
    Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    Call objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase("H:\VBA\Array Practice\Database1array.accdb")
    objAccess.CurrentProject.Connection.Execute ("ALTER TABLE Company ADD COLUMN employee CHAR ")
End Sub
```

```vb
Sub insertvalues()
    Dim objAccess As Object
    Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    Call objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase("H:\VBA\Array Practice\Database1array.accdb")
    objAccess.CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "INSERT INTO Employee (Gross) VALUES LEFT([full_name], 3)"
End Sub
```

I am able to create a new column but could't insert the value.

Comment: I am unsure if my sql query will run and there is a possibility to do this and create column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly update the table using column FULL_NAME instead of inserting. I have tested the following code and it is working.

```
Sub test()
Dim dbs As Database
Set dbs = OpenDatabase("Database1.accdb")  
dbs.Execute "UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET GROSS=LEFT(FULL_NAME, 3)"
dbs.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Please vote the answer if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You added a column to a table named Company, but you are attempting to insert values to a table named employee.

If the table named company as records then an update statement is what you need to add values into the new column employee, but if the table does not have any record, then an insert statement can be used to add values into the employee field.